# PdfStamper being disposed

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, idisposable, pdfstamper

The PdfStamper I'm passing in to this method is being disposed of at the end of the method - why, and how do I stop it? I'm trying to create a page object from the template, which I can then add to the PdfStamper X number of times.

```
//real code
public void DoSpecialAction(PdfStamper pdfStamper)
{
    using (var pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(_extraPageTemplatePath))
    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate))
    {
        PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
        pdfStamper.InsertPage(3, pdfReader.GetPageSize(1));
        PdfContentByte pb = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(3);
        pb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

the program structure is as follows:

```
//psuedocode
class PrintFieldsToPdf {
    foreach (normalfield) {
        PrintNormalFields();
    }

    foreach (specialaction) {
        DoSpecialAction(pdfStamper);
    }

    pdfStamper.Close(); //at this point the object has been deallocated
}
```

Throwing the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot access a closed file.
```

Comment: Can you provide a [short, self contained, compilable, example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Also define "disposed". That's a very strange word. Do you mean it becomes `null`? And what is the `pdfTemplate` instance about? Why do you create two different `PdfReader` instances? Your code looks awkward. If you want to add *the same page* multiple times, your approach will result in a bloated file with the same bytes repeated over and over again. Using elementary logic, you should be able to add the same page multiple times *reusing* the Form XObject.

Comment: the PdfStamper comes from outside of this method. It is incased in a class that generically populates a form with fields. It doesn't care what those fields are. This particular method is part of a class that provides additional special actions to forms of varying types. In order to preserve the populators ability to not care what kind of form it is populating, it has a dictionary of fields that would trigger special actions and the special actions that are triggered.

This special action will add an extra page to handle text overflow from a particular field.

Comment: Instead of just saying that it is being "disposed" can you be more specific? The `IDisposable` contract only enforces that a method called `Dispose` gets invoked but not what it actually does. Instead, are you getting an exception about a closed stream?

Comment: Also, I didn't write all of this code. The using statements were written by someone else. I haven't changed them as I have assumed they had a reason for doing so. When the method exits, the calling method then calls PdfStamper.Close(). This is throwing an exception on the basis that the object is not there. I've peaked inside at that point and all its members are null

Comment: Is `PdfStamper.Close();` a casing typo? `PdfStamper` is a class, not an object (unless you explicitly did that) and therefore cannot be closed.

Comment: that part is psuedocode designed to show you how it is structured and which elements are causing the problems where.

Comment: Thanks Mark, we just had to be sure. Can you post the actual exception that you are receiving? Unless you are using `ref` parameters there's no way for a method to unset a variable and an instance cannot unset itself. Unfortunately psuedocode can hide the smallest mistakes and since your real code appears completely legit my gut instinct says that your problem is in whatever's calling it.

Comment: I have a hunch it may be that the page object never actually gets copied until the PdfStamper calls Close and writes the file, and therefore the PdfReader I'm using to read the extra page template is causing the issue, as it is disposed of at the end of my method, before PdfStamper is closed.

Comment: You might want to try `pdfStamper.Writer.FreeReader(pdfReader)` at the end of your `using` block

Comment: Thank you mkl, that works exactly as I want it to, cheers!

Comment: @Mark Great! I made it an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP eventually commented:

> I have a hunch it may be that the page object never actually gets copied until the `PdfStamper` calls `Close` and writes the file, and therefore the `PdfReader` I'm using to read the extra page template is causing the issue, as it is disposed of at the end of my method, before `PdfStamper` is closed.

His hunch was correct: The copying of at least certain parts of the original page is delayed until the `PdfStamper` is being closed. This allows for certain optimizations in case multiple pages from the same `PdfReader` instance are imported in separate calls.

The use case of imports from many different `PdfReaders` had also been on the mind of the iText(Sharp) developers. So they provided a way to tell the `PdfStamper` to copy everything required from a given `PdfReader` at the time the user is sure he won't copy anything else from it:

```
public void DoSpecialAction(PdfStamper pdfStamper)
{
    using (var pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(_extraPageTemplatePath))
    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate))
    {
        PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
        pdfStamper.InsertPage(3, pdfReader.GetPageSize(1));
        PdfContentByte pb = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(3);
        pb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        // Copy everything required from the PdfReader
        pdfStamper.Writer.FreeReader(pdfReader);
    }
}
```